# VACUUM FULL restored very small amount of disk space

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I have a large table with ~130m entries. I recently removed unnecessary entries and it should be left with ~60m.

I ran `VACUUM(FULL) [table_name]` and after it finally finished it restored only 2GB of disk space, while I expected it to be ~20GB. Also it seems that only 10m entries were removed after vacuuming. The `VACUUM(FULL)` finished successfuly and it had enough disk space.

What could cause this? Can this occupied space be recovered somehow?

Answer (score 1):

If there is an open snapshot that can theoretically still see the deleted data, then that data has to be copied over into the new table by VACUUM FULL.  Check pg_stat_activity.